# Fields (Matrix) side by side?

Tags: matrix, craft3, field

In ExpressionEngine it was possible to have fields side by side.

[image]

So when creating a entry you had all options (for example for an image) in one row.

[image]

I can't figure out how to do that in Craft

Comment: You can't do this native in Craft right now, but this thread may interest you: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2644 
Looks like some cool things are in the backlog.

Comment: @Johann Dyck: I found the Neon plugin and seems like with it you can also achieve that. But not available for Craft 3 yet and looks complicated.

Comment: Yep, I meant to designate Craft 3 specifically.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to replicate this behaviour, is to use the [Super Table plugin](https://github.com/verbb/super-table). It lets you create all of Craft's fields within table rows.

Comment: Already played with it. But you can't have a row with multiple columns and directly under it another row with just one column? There is also the table field - but there you don't have for example dropdown.